# Improving buffer read write speeds in Android (in comparison with a desktop C# based application)

Tags: c#, android, performance

I ve converted some C# code to Java/Android code. Basically I am decrypting a file(say a.mp4.enc) on the sdcard and writing it back to the private data folder(/data/app/a.mp4). Now the same thing happens on the desktop system and the code is so

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*10];
int len;
while ((len = cryptostream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    buffer = new byte[1024*10];
}
```

And on the android emulator I run the following :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];
int len = cryptoStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
while (len > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    len = cryptoStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
}
```

But the C# code takes 0.1 s for a 6mb file conversion while the emulator takes 20 minutes! Is there something wrong with my code or is it just the emulator and the Android way because it seems too long!! Is there something I need to do differently? I ve tried not reading from the SD Card but from the app data folder itself kbut there is no significant improvement in performance.

Comment: I haven't done any c# on android - however, the first thing I would do would be to determine the relative time for reading vs. writing. I suspect the main culprit would be reading from cryptoStream. And then dig deeper to find out exactly why it is taking so long.. ideally you would want to dig into the implementation, but I don't know how feasible that is with the c# stuff for android.

Comment: Hi, Actually there s no C# stuff on Android - its just C# code in Desktop converted to Java code for Android :D . Thanks though!  Let me look at the cryptoStream again

Comment: It was my understanding that there was a c# runtime for android? Is that not the same thing as what you are using, or am I just confused? :)